# Is it possible to set a part of a select statement in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query of which the `select`-part is really long. I'd like to split this in several pieces, especially because some parts are in there twice or even more often.

What I'd like is something like the following:

```
Declare @SQLPart as varchar(1000)
Set @SQLPart = 'Field1,
                case ... as Field2,'

Select ..., @SQLPart, ... From .....
```

Unfortunately this results error messages. I tried something like `EXEC(@SQLPart)` as well but of course this also didn't work. How would I solve this?

Comment: You should use `mssql dynamic sql`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, dynamic sql and [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE ##Temp (Field1 int, Field2 int)

Declare @SQLPart nvarchar(1000)
Set @SQLPart = N'Field1, Field2 '

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000) = N'SELECT ' + @SQLPart + 'FROM ##Temp'
PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

DROP TABLE ##Temp
```

Your SQL code must be `nvarchar` type.
Alse `sp_executesql` is better than `EXECUTE` function, when you have many similar queries, `sp_executesql` caches executaion plans, and it can be better in perfomance.

Comment: @Grafit can you accept my answer or you need some comments?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic sql here,and use a `EXECUTE` keyword to execute this dynamic query

```
Declare @SQLPart as varchar(1000)
Set @SQLPart = 'Field1,
                case ... as Field2,'

EXECUTE ('SELECT ....,'+@SQLPart+',... FROM ...')
```

Comment: Using 'EXEC' is not a preferred choice.
It is preferred to use the answer provided by Backs, which uses `sp_executesql`. This is so because `EXECUTE` or `EXEC` allows for SQL  injection to happen, in case the fields contain some form of a query entered by a customer. In that case our database/data might become vulnerable to attacks from foreign sources.
Hence it is advised to use `sp_executesql` instead.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not support Macro-Substitution, so you would have to use Dynamic SQL.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) ='Select ... ' + @SQLPart + '... from ...'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Using 'EXEC' is not a preferred choice.
It is preferred to use the answer provided by Backs, which uses `sp_executesql`. This is so because `EXECUTE` or `EXEC` allows for SQL  injection to happen, in case the fields contain some form of a query entered by a customer. In that case our database/data might become vulnerable to attacks from foreign sources.
Hence it is advised to use `sp_executesql` instead.